# How do I change from question mark (?) to slash (/) on URL MVC Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

Currently I have pdf file that shows on the page correctly but the URL shows as "/Test?id=name.pdf" and I want it to show as "/Test/name.pdf". How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

.cshtml

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Trees", "Park", new { id = "name.pdf" })" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Trees(string id)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/folder1/folder2/{0}", id));

    string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    return File(path, mime);
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "testing",
        url: "Test/{filename}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Park", action = "Trees", filename  = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I already checked these similar questions [ASP.NET MVC Routing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434076/asp-net-mvc-routing-question) [How do I get rid of the question mark in an ASP.NET MVC route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231198/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-question-mark-in-an-asp-net-mvc-route) but none of those solutions helped me, maybe is cause I have a @Url.Action with new { id = "name.pdf" } and that could be the difference since none of those questions had that.

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution!

So it came down to two things: eliminating the `id = UrlParameter.Optional` on RouteConfig.cs which causes the question mark (?), AND understanding that apparently you can't put a dot (.) inside the brackets {}, because if you try to do so, then the brackets {} won't accept the input and thus the path would be incorrect.

So, here is how the code looks updated:

.cshtml

```
//Took out .pdf so that the brackets on the controller can read the input
<a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Trees", "Park", new { filename = "name" })" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Trees(string filename)
{
    //Added .pdf after the {}, ideally this wouldn't be hard coded but that's out of
    //the scope of this question/problem
    string path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/folder1/folder2/{0}.pdf", filename));

    string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    return File(path, mime);
}
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "testing",
        url: "Test/{filename}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Park", action = "Trees"}
        //Remove the URLParameter.Optional
    );
```

This results in the PDF opening successfully AND the URL to be Test/name with the slash (/) and not the question mark (?). The only thing to 'fix' is for the URL to also show the extension (.pdf), but that's for another question in another thread. But for replacing the question mark (?) with the slashes (/) AND opening the PDF successfully, this solution achieves that and answers my original question.

Answer (score 5):

Your route url parameter is `Test/{filename}` hence `filename` should replace `id` parameter in your cshtml and controller.

EDIT: You need to add your route above the default route and add a parameter to webconfig module. We also need to edit the webconfig because by default they don't support the `.` symbol.

EDIT 2: Don't forget to add the directory or file to Visual studio solution.

routeconfig.cs: Add the route before the default route.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "testing",
      url: "Test/{filename}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Park", action = "Trees", filename = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
}
```

webconfig: Add the parameter `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to modules node.

```
<system.webserver>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      ...
   </modules>
</system.webserver>
```

cshtml:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Trees", "Park", new { @filename = "name.pdf" })" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Trees(string filename)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/folder1/folder2/{0}", filename));

    string mime = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    return File(path, mime);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209687/discussion-on-answer-by-jerdine-sabio-how-do-i-change-from-question-mark-to).

Comment: For those who see this comment or up-vote it, please note that this is not the solution as this results in the pdf not showing on the page.

Comment: @UltimateTechDiscovery push your project to github or at least a simple version of it. And let me have a look. The code above works perfectly on my end.

Comment: I found the solution. The errors where trying to pass a dot (.) which the brackets {} wouldn't take and thus causing the path to not read successfully, and by trying to use UrlParameter.Optional which caused the question mark (?). With my solution (which is posted below) I can both access the PDF successfully AND the URL shows with slashes (/) and not with question marks (?). Only thing left though is to also show the extension (.pdf) on the URL as well as not hard-coding the .pdf in the controller and perhaps using a meme function, etc; but I'll open another question for that soon.